# Storing extra data in XD plugins

Tags: javascript, plugins, adobe-xd

My XD plugin needs to store extra data like user preferences and history. Does XD developer APIs allow me to do that? Which APIs can I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no key-value store available yet in Adobe XD, but you can use the [Storage APIs](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/uxp/storage-index.html) to read and write persistent data. For example:

```
const fs = require("uxp").storage.localFileSystem;
let prefs = {
    theme: "blue",
};
async function savePrefs() {
    const settingsFolder = await fs.getDataFolder();
    try {
        const settingsFile = await settingsFolder.createFile("settings.json", {overwrite: true});
        await settingsFile.write(JSON.stringify(prefs));            
    } catch(err) {
        /* handle errors */
    }
}
async function readPrefs() {
    const settingsFolder = await fs.getDataFolder();
    try {
        const settingsFile = await settingsFolder.getEntry("settings.json");
        prefs = JSON.parse(await settingsFile.read());
    } catch(err) {
        /* handle errors; can also occur if settings haven't been saved yet */
    }
}
```

There's also this [nice abstraction library that handles key-value storage](https://github.com/pklaschka/xd-storage-helper) written by [Pablo Klaschka](https://github.com/pklaschka), which makes working with storage even simpler.